# Loop "paste" function over multiple files in the same folder

Tags: unix

I'm trying to concatenate horizontally a number of files (1000) `*.txt` in a folder.

How can I loop over the files using the "paste" function?

NB: all the `*.txt` files are in the same directory.

Comment: try for i in $* do paste $i p.txt done

Comment: What's wrong with just `paste *.txt`?

Comment: Satya, take a look at the man page for `paste`. It makes no sense to use `paste` on one file at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why loop? You can use wildcards.

```
paste *.txt > combined.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, it would be a question of just calling `paste *.txt` (and redirecting the output: `paste *.txt > output.txt`, as @zx did). Try it, but you'll be generating some enormously long lines. If `paste` can`t handle the line length you'll be generating, you'll have to reproduce its effect using a scripting language that has no line length limit, like perl or python.

Another possible sticking point is if your shell can't handle this many arguments in the expansion of the glob `*.txt`. Again, you can solve that with a script. It's easy to do so if that's your situation, let us know here.

PS. Given what `paste` does, looping is **not** going to do it for you: You (presumably) need the file contents side by side in the output, not one after the other.